# Laravel 4 routes going to wrong route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've set up routes for a resource and added additional routes for the same controller. I've had this route working and don't think I've changed anything but now it's routing to the wrong method in the controller.

I'm aware of the first in and first out principle of the routes and have this set up at the moment:

```
Route::post('products/addItemToCart', array('uses' => 'ProductsController@addItemToCart'));
Route::post('products/editItemInCart', array('uses' => 'ProductsController@editItemInCart'));
//Product Related Routes
Route::get('products/saletotal/{id}', function ($id) {
        return Product::groupedSales($id);
    });

Route::get('products/itemValue/{id}', array('uses' => 'ProductsController@itemValue'));
Route::get('products/cartitem/{id}', array('uses' => 'ProductsController@getCartItem'));

Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
```

I have a form which POSTS to `products/addItemToCart` for some reason this no longer uses the method `addItemToCart` but is going to the controllers show method and treating the 2nd parameter as an ID of the record to find.

I placed a var_dump at the start of the show method to identify the value being passed to the show method which is `addItemToCart`

It's as if the routes file is ignoring the previous routes and skipping to the defaults in the resource route.

Any ideas what mistakes I've made?

Thanks

Update: additional code for fuller picture:

The POST is generated by javascript with this method:

```
if($('#rowId').val() !=="") {
    postUrl = "/products/editItemInCart";
} else {
    postUrl = "/products/addItemToCart";
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: postUrl,
    data: item,
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(result) {
        //update the displayed Cart
        var data = result;
        updateCart();

    }
});
```

item is an array

The method in Products controller are:

```
<?php
//updated 08-11-2013

class ProductsController extends BaseController {

/**
 * Product Repository
 *
 * @var Product
 */
protected $product;

public function __construct(Product $product)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}

public function addItemToCart() {

    $product = Product::find( Input::get( 'id' ) );
   //method code
}

**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    dd($id);

    $product = $this->product->findOrFail($id);

    return View::make('products.show', compact('product'));
}
```

the show method is being used instead of the expected addToCart method as specified in the URL and route

I can see the exected items in the POST from within firebug

Comment: Could you post the view code that generates the form, as well as `ProductController` relevant methods? It's difficult to see what's going on without these.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the parameter expectation to the route string.

```
Route::post('products/addItemToCart/{id}', array('uses' => 'ProductsController@addItemToCart'));
```

Otherwise the resource controller interprets this as `products/{param}/{param}` hence why it goes to the default `post` implementation of the controller.

Comment: OK - tried that but not working. The request is coming from a form as POST so there shouldn't be the need for a parameter. I can see in firebug that the POST request is made. Strangely the method it's routing to is a GET method. Also if I remove the resource and just leave the POST method in place I get a methodnotallowed exception which I'm assuming relates to trying to use a POST method with a GET method.

Comment: I have the same routes set up on a live server and they work perfectly but not on my development server.

Comment: Are both you're live and Dev on the exactly the same version of Laravel? There was a tweak to routes a while ago that meant you had to be explicit about parameters.

Comment: I've managed to fix by deleting the routes file and rebuilsing. I can't see a difference but it works now